# Infinite ajax scroll, php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using infinite ajax scroll. The values from the database are fetched properly. But when I scroll down, the same results from 0 to 10 are displayed. I don't know where I made a mistake.

The query is printed in [this link](http://tamil.kornerseat.com/news1.php). How can I make the query dynamic, by incrementing next 10 results? Currently, the same results are displayed when I scroll.

```
<?php include_once('../inc/header.php')?>

<?php

$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
echo $page;
# find out query stat point
$start = (($page * $limit) - $limit);

# sql query
$SQL = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM review_news WHERE category='%s' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", 
mysql_real_escape_string($category), 0, 10);

print $SQL;
# query for dataset
$ResDataSet  = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

# query for page navigation
$ResFoundRow = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS NumRow") or die( mysql_error() );
$RowFoundRow = mysql_fetch_array($ResFoundRow);


if ( $RowFoundRow['NumRow'] <= 0) 
{

    echo 'Page not found!';
    exit();
} else if( $RowFoundRow['NumRow'] > ($page * $limit) ) {


   $next = ++$page;
}

?>          
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
        jQuery.ias({
            container : '#loop', // main container where data goes to append
            item: '.review', // single items
            pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
            next: '.nav a', // next page selector
            loader: '<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
            triggerPageThreshold: 3 // show load more if scroll more than this
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
/*Loader style*/
.ias_loader, .ias_trigger {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 30px 0 40px;
}
.ias_trigger a:link,
.ias_trigger a:visited {
    padding: 4px 50px;

    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ias_trigger a:hover,
.ias_trigger a:active {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
</style>

<div  class="content left" >
<!--  CONTENT AREA START -->


        <div id="loop" class="list-view clear">

     <h3><span>Recent News</span>
           </h3>           

        <?php
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ResDataSet)){


        ?>              




            <div id="post_76" class="review type-review status-publish hentry post">
                <div class="post-content">
                                        <a class="post_img" href="review-default-news.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>"><img  src="<?php
                            if($row['image_name']=="")
                            {

                             echo  'http://www.kornerseat.com/news/noimage.jpg';

                                }else{
                                    ?>http://www.kornerseat.com/news/<?php echo $row['image_name'];?> <?php }?>" alt="<?php echo $row['heading'];?>" title="<?php echo $row['heading'];?>"  /> </a>

                    <div class="post_content">
                        <h2><a class="widget-title" href="review-default-news.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($fetch_news['id']);?>"><?php echo $row['heading'];?></a></h2> 

                        <div class="post_right">
                            <!--<a href="#" class="pcomments" >4 </a>   -->

                        </div>

                        <p> 
                        <?php

if(strlen($row['news'])<=65)
  {
    echo $row['news'];
  }else{
    $y=substr($row['news'],0,150) . '...';
    echo $y;
  }
  ?>
                        <a href="review-default-news.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>" class="read_more"> Read More </a></p> 
                    </div>     
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php
                }
            ?>

        <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href='news1.php?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif?>

                        </div>


<!--  CONTENT AREA END -->
</div>
<?php include_once('../inc/right.php')?>
<?php include_once('../inc/footer.php')?>
```

Comment: Your query is always selecting first 10 results

    # sql query
$SQL = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM review_news WHERE category='%s' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", 
mysql_real_escape_string($category), 0, 10);

Comment: yes .How to make it to select next ten results

Comment: look the answer, what value has the $limit variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$limit` to correctly calculate `$start`, and then use `$start` and `$limit` in the query

```
$limit = 10;
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
echo $page;
# find out query stat point
$start = (($page * $limit) - $limit);

# sql query
$SQL = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM review_news WHERE category='%s' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", 
mysql_real_escape_string($category), $start, $limit);
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string($category), 0, 10);` is your issue.

Change it to;

```
mysql_real_escape_string($category), $start, 10);
```

Comment: I have made the mistake some where in the loop while incrementing the next results after ten is not getting in my database there are 72 results the first ten is repeatedly displaying. i need it to make dyanmic

Comment: i have made the changes as u said http://tamil.kornerseat.com/news1.php still the same result